# How to add dependencies to Mulesoft Design Center (IPaSS)

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft

I want to add the Google spreadsheet connector [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoADN.png) to my Mulesoft Design Center (IPaSS) Project. When I click the plus button and search google spreadsheet, I can't see the connector in the palette. Please check the attached screenshot.
Also, I cannot see any functionality to add dependencies that are not available in the IPaSS. Please note I'm using a trial version.

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoADN.png) https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/org.mule.modules/mule-module-google-spreadsheet/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the connector your are pointing in Anypoint Exchange is a Mule 3 connector. [Flow Designer](https://docs.mulesoft.com/design-center/about-designing-a-mule-application) in Design Center -the feature that you are using to develop the project- only supports Mule 4 connectors.

Comment: How can I use Mule 3 connectors in the project?

Comment: So we cannot create integrations related to Gsheets in Flow designer IPaSS?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an existing Mule 4 connector for Google Sheets available in Anypoint Exchange. If you create a RAML description of Google Sheets REST API, or develop a connector for Mule 4, then you can publish it to Exchange and use it with Flow Designer.